# How to re-compile a compiled bytecode listing for Lua's VM/compiler?

Tags: android, lua, compilation, bytecode

I'm attempting to modify the code of an old mobile game called Fun Run 2 as a unique research project for my software engineering course in college.

The app was made using the Corona SDK and therefore is programmed in Lua. So, once I got my hands on the APK and decompressed it, I needed to unpack the resource.car (Corona ARchive) to gain access to the Lua files. So I did, and all the files inside that archive are pre-compiled .lu files.

The first thing I tried in order to modify the Lua code was to use unluac/luadec to decompile the .lu files into readable, modifiable, able-to-be-compiled source code. I was able to successfully decompile, modify, and recompile them, however when it got to actually executing the modified .lu file in the game, it crashed because of something to do with attempting to index a nil value. I discovered that the cause of this was the fact that there is something called an upvalue, which when debug information is stripped from a compiled Lua file, are impossible to retrieve, and therefore trying to decompile and recompile the .lu files wasn't going to work.

So my next approach was to use the `luac -l` approach, which creates a listing of the compiled bytecode for Lua's virtual machine.

The results of `luac -l lua.gameLogic.powerUpChance.lu` were along the lines of

```
...
main <?:0,0> (11 instructions, 44 bytes at 025D7D80)
0+ params, 3 slots, 0 upvalues, 0 locals, 4 constants, 2 functions
    1   [-] NEWTABLE    0 0 0
    2   [-] GETGLOBAL   1 -1    ; require
    3   [-] LOADK       2 -2    ; "composer"
    4   [-] CALL        1 2 2
    5   [-] CLOSURE     2 0 ; 025D8280
    6   [-] MOVE        0 1
    7   [-] SETTABLE    0 -3 2  ; "selectRandomPowerUp" -
...
```

Given this list of instructions, I knew what I needed to modify and where to modify it, and I did so. Which brings me to my question - how do I take the modified bytecode listing and compile it back into a compiled .lu file? Is this even possible? Is this approach to modifying compiled Lua files a waste of my time?

Comment: Please upload your bytecode file.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Here you go, this is the unmodified version - https://pastebin.com/gZjFsKDL

Comment: I was asking about bytecode binary file, not its listing.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff My mistake, here you are - https://ufile.io/hu26d

Comment: OK, it's usual Lua 5.1 x86 bytecode without debug info.  This file should be decompiled and recompiled without problems.  All upvalues are described inside (except their names), no additional information is needed.  Show the decompilation result (to check if decompilation was performed correctly).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff The immediate deompilation result is https://pastebin.com/Jievk4iF Just to test and make sure that the reason the game was crashing was because of faulty de/recompilation, I didn't modify anything, recompiled it, and as expected, the game still crashed. I'm not new to programming by any means but I am new to Lua, and this whole project has left me scratching my head regarding the concept of upvalues and whatnot.

Comment: Probably, your decompiler works incorrectly with upvalues (I don't know where to get a correct decompiler).  Insert the following line at the beginning of program: `local _UPVALUE0_ = require("composer")`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff You are a godsend my friend. That's the one thing I hadn't tried. Thanks!!

Comment: The reason unluac doesn't work is that the debug info is stripped (and I have done hardly any work on this case). Theoretically, Lua Assembly Tools is supposed to support editable bytecode listsings (in its own format), but I haven't had good luck with it working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There's no tool (none that I know of, at least) for compiling the string representation of the byte code back into proper Lua bytecode; mostly because that's not meant to be edited, but as a way to check what your Lua code compiles to and possibly optimize it.

A better solution would be to use a tool that decompiles the byte code into Lua code. Which tool to use for this depends heavily on what version of Lua you're using, but for anything from 5.1 to 5.3 theres [LuaDec](https://github.com/viruscamp/luadec), which I haven't personally tried, but should get the job done. Once you have decompiled the source, make all necessary modifications and compile it again with luac as you would do with any Lua file.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that method, with no dice :( I was able to decompile, modify, and recompile the Lua files this way, but during runtime I get errors regarding attempts to access nil values. I found out that this is because local variables are sometimes "upvalues" which can't be seen/used for some reason. More specifically, before decompilation, there are "GETUPVAL" instructions, and when I recompile, they become "GETGLOBAL" instructions. I know it's possible to get around this because other people have successfully modified this game's code using this method but I have no idea how.

Comment: Hmmm... I see the problem there, but it's easy to avoid that problem. You just have to identify which variables are upvalues, then add them as locals outside of the function, so the function will have them as upvalues. Then you should be able to `string.dump` the function with its upvalues.

Comment: I see... finding out which variables are upvalues is easy, but in that case, how would I find out what to declare the local as outside of the function if the upvalues are referenced and used like so? https://pastebin.com/bZAkELZa

Comment: In that case it should be enough to just write `local _UPVALUE0_` before the function, and it should be compiled as an upvalue. But remember to only switch out the bytecode of the method itself, not the part that actually creates the closure :)

Comment: @xn I would suggest looking for existing questions or creating a new one for this though, since it's drifting further and further away from your original question. Be sure to add some more context while you're at it, like how exactly you extracted the bytecode, how it's executed, /[ph]astebins/ of the decompiled code, etc. If you can't boil it down to a single stackoverflow question, you can also just ask on the lua subreddit, which isn't as strict about questions being concise and to the point as SO.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the decompiler you're using fails to correctly decompile for-loops.
The following fragment:

```
if A1_3 == #A3_5 and A2_4 > 2 then
   for _FORV_9_ = 1, #A3_5 do
   end
   if _FOR_ then
      L5_7 = 11
   end
end
```

must look like this:

```
if A1_3 == # A3_5 and A2_4 > 2 then
   local R6 = true
   for k = 1, #A3_5 do
      if not A3_5[k].mainPlayer then
         if A3_5[k].x < A0_2.x + 1200 then
            R6 = false
         end
      end
   end
   if R6 then
      L5_7 = 11
   end
end
```